# Shortcuts within Find/Replace dialog do not work in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As shown in this screenshot there are 5 occurrences of the "Find" field. But hitting `CMD-ENTER` -as shown in the shortcut balloon help - does *nothing*.

[image]
Why is it not working/ what can be done to get it to to work?  I detest using the mouse for extremely common operations especially Find/Replace.

Comment: Hmm, it is `Ctrl+Alt+Enter` on Windows.  Can you try the mac equivalent and see if it works.  And if you search for the command `editor.action.replaceAll` in your Keyboard Shortcuts what is it bound to?  FInally, any chance something else besides replaceAll is bound to `CMD-ENTER`?

Comment: @Mark Nice suggestions.  `CMD-ENTER` is not globally attached so it is available.  OH! Just found it after trial and error;  `CMD-OPTion-ENTER` . You gave the inspiration to find it - would you like to put an answer? if not I'll put one

Comment: Thanks, I posted an answer.  Do you think that the tooltip is an error?

Comment: Well it's certainly an error but details are unknown e.g. is it not/mis- reading the keybindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little odd that the binding is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the Mac, whereas it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows?  Things to try:

1. The equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the Mac (and you indicated that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> does work).
2. Check in the `Gear Icon/KeyboardShortcuts` editor what the command `editor.actions.replaceAll` is bound to.
3. Check in the Keyboard Shortcuts (click on the little keyboard icon to the right and type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) to see if it is bound to something besides `editor.actions.replaceAll`.
4. You can run the `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` command from the Command Palette, type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and see what command vscode finds for that keybinding.

You indicated that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> does work as you expect.